# What is difference between 新疆 and 新疆生产建设兵团?

Tags: proper-nouns

In the reports of COVID-19 pandemic situation, China's media often make special mention of 新疆生产建设兵团 after the provinces,autonomous regions and municipalities under the direct administration of central government.

What is the difference of 新疆 and 新疆生产建设兵团？Is it like the State of Washington and Washington District of Columbia, or New York City and New York State?

Comment: Here's the answer from Baidu: http://www.iyinyueta.com/q-7218.html

Comment: @dan Thank you for your resource, but what does this mean in your data 你愿意做我的小火车永远不出轨，那我就愿意做你的小美人鱼永远不劈腿?

Comment: It's an analogy or metaphor as if saying if you don't part ways, I won't either. It's an expression to describe one's attitude towards a relation.

Comment: The Wiki page on the XPCC should have all the information you’re looking for: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinjiang_Production_and_Construction_Corps

Comment: @dan Does this sentence figuratively illustrate the relations of 新疆 and 新疆生产建设兵团?

Comment: @dan Does this sentence figuratively illustrate the relations of 新疆 and 新疆生产建设兵团?

Comment: @NanningYouth It seems that this sentence is unrelated. I think it's an editing error there.

Comment: 新疆生产建设兵团 is located in  新疆, but it is administrated by the central government.

Comment: @lxg By the way, is there the same organization in other autonomous regions like Tibet, Inner Mongolia, Ningxia, and Guangxi?

Comment: @Mou某 I regret to say that my internet access is denied to this info, could you paste part of the content?

Comment: The former is a province in China, equivalent to the State in the US. The latter is a government-sponsored group with the given mission to help the economical and infrastructure development in that province. Yes, there could be similar groups at other underdeveloped locations in China. The one in 新疆 carries political means as well.

Comment: @NanningYouth Tibet, Ningxia and Guangxi -------No.
Inner Mongolia, Heilongjiang, Yunnan ------ In history, yes. For now, nope.

Comment: @r13 to be accurate, Xinjiang is not a province, it is an autonomous region (at province level). Btw, I do not think this question is related to the language...

Comment: I am outdated on the turn of event: "新疆省（维吾尔语：شىجاڭ ئۆلكىسى‎），簡稱新或疆，是中華民國法理上及中國歷史上存在的省份。清朝光緒十年（1884年）置，治迪化市。長期以來由中華民國地方軍閥實質統治至中華人民共和國初期，在1955年被新成立的「新疆維吾爾自治區」取代；而中華民國的新疆省至民國三十八年（1949年）前後遷至台北市四維路52巷31號辦公（新疆省政府辦事處），於民國八十一年（1992年）1月16日裁撤，至此無該省的省政府編制。"

Answer (score 3):

In the history, Xinjiang was firstly ruled by China in Han dynasty about 2000 years ago, which was even earlier than Tibet, Manchuria and Mongolia. The main purpose of controlling it is squeezing the living space of nomads in the North and maintaining trade routes with Central Asia (the Silk Road).

Because of the poverty of Xinjiang and long distance from the central plains, the rule in Xinjiang inflicted incredibly-steep costs on central governments of different dynasties. Any event (civil strife in the Central Plains, the invasion of Northern Nomads, local rebellion in Xinjiang, and etc.) will cause that central government lose control of Xinjiang. In fact, the central government had no effective jurisdiction over Xinjiang for more than half of the 2000 years.

In this background, most governments pursued a policy named 屯垦制 in the history. This policy allows garrisons to carry out production activities in peacetime. It improves local supply capacity and enlarges influence of central government. Although it abandoned professionalization of the army, it tied Xinjiang to central plains of China with lower cost in belif.

In the 1950s, after the establish of PRC, Chinese government decided to follow this ancient policy. And this is the origin of 新疆生产建设兵团.

But today, it is hard to make a simple defination on it.

It is a new concept in geograph. You can use 新疆生产建设兵团 as your address. Every unit with an official designation in 新疆生产建设兵团 has its own station, which covers an area of 70600 km² in total.

It can be considered as a state-owned company. Every product from 新疆生产建设兵团 will be printed with "produced by 新疆生产建设兵团".

It also can be regarded as a local government. After 70 years of development, there are more than three million people guided by 新疆生产建设兵团 directly.

As for its significance in military, I think 新疆生产建设兵团 has lost it in some extent. Since the improvement of Sino-Soviet relations in the 1980s, the independence of 新疆生产建设兵团 has been reduced by China's Ministry of National Defence. And Chinese govenment established Western Military Region to replace it formally in 2016.

Emm... I think you might get more confusion in it when you read here, right?

In the case that you mentioned in your statement, you can just understand 新疆生产建设兵团 as a geographical term. A special province beyonds the other normal provinces, autonomous regions and municipalities.

Nominally, the government of 新疆生产建设兵团 response to both Autonomous Region Government of Xinjiang and Central Government. In fact, it can be regarded as an province government directly under the jurisdiction of the central government in Xinjiang.

Make an example. There is a family with 3 members. Central government is daddy. Government of Xinjiang Autonomous Region（新疆自治区政府）and 新疆生产建设兵团 are sons. 新疆自治区政府 is the elder one and 新疆生产建设兵团 is the younger one. In the daily life, 新疆生产建设兵团 ask elder brother (新疆自治区政府) for help. But when there are some events, 新疆生产建设兵团 will return to central government directly.

And now, big event is coming (COVID-19). 新疆生产建设兵团 reports to central government directly instead of reporting to 新疆自治区政府 firstly. So the report from 新疆自治区政府 does not contain 新疆生产建设兵团, and China's media need to make special mention of 新疆生产建设兵团 after the provinces,autonomous regions and municipalities under the direct administration of central government.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like @whx has put up a fairly detailed answer already, I'm just posting the info from Wikipedia as requested by OP:

[Xinjiang Production and Construction Corps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinjiang_Production_and_Construction_Corps)

> The Xinjiang Production and Construction Corps (Chinese: 新疆生产建设兵团; pinyin: Xīnjiāng Shēngchǎn Jiànshè Bīngtuán), also known as XPCC or Bingtuan ("The Corps"), is a unique state-owned economic and paramilitary organization in the Xinjiang Uyghur Autonomous Region (XUAR) of China. The XPCC has administrative authority over several medium-sized cities as well as settlements and farms in Xinjiang. It has its own administrative structure, fulfilling governmental functions such as healthcare, policing, judiciary, and education for areas under its jurisdiction. Nominally subject to the XUAR, its internal affairs, including the administration of its cities and reclaimed land, is separate from that of the Autonomous Region and under direct control of the central government. The XPCC has been described to operate as a state within a state.

There is additional info on the page if you wish to read further.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you may say there are two province units exist in one province, they manage their own business and they are on same level.

Not like the relations between New York City and New York State.

By the way, I was born in "Xinjiang Production and Construction Corps".

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean you were born in New York State or in Xinjiang Corps? I do not see clearly what "the latter" refers to in your answer. Previously I asked the same question to a person born in Xinjiang, she did not know such things but she is a graduate student studying in the US after her college education in China.

Comment: @NanningYouth I mean I was born in Xinjiang.
Young generations do not care about that.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between 新疆 and 新疆生产建设兵团 (Xinjiang Production and Construction Corps) is the same as the difference between "New York" and "New York One World Trade Center"

One World Trade Center is a building in New York

新疆生产建设兵团 is a production and construction group in Xinjiang

In Toronto, we only call our highest building "CN Tower", but people outside of Toronto might refer it as "Toronto CN Tower"

Comment: I am afraid you do not seem to have understood the question itself, but still I appreciate your help.

Comment: @NanningYouth you ask: "What is the difference of 新疆 and 新疆生产建设兵团?" So the difference is as I stated. Or you wanted  to ask  what is "新疆生产建设兵团?"

Comment: Haha, you are very clever. But you have intentionally ignored the first paragraph of my question. You are not a retired lawyer, are you?

Comment: The example you gave is like the case of Scotland and Scotland Yard

Answer (score 0):

It is the only 屯垦兵团 in China now.

**It is a mix of a party committee of 新疆, an administration of local government(the autonomous regions), a military unit(兵团), a company(中国新建集团公司).**

The leader of the 新疆生产建设兵团(the first secretary of the 兵团's party committee) is also the leader of the autonomous regions(the secretary of autonomous region's party committee).

Under the leadership, there is a manager (it is also a company) who is also the commander of the 兵团.